# Return type of an anonymous function

Tags: dart

I am reading about dart and one think that confuses me is the the syntax for anonymous functions. Specifically, how do I specify the type of the returned value for such a function.

For example, consider the following:

```
var f = (int x) {return x + 1;};
```

In this instance, I am declaring that the type of the parameter `x` is `int`. How can I explicitly say that the function returns an `int`? I understand that the compiler will probably figure that out using type inference, but I want to explicitly specify the type to prevent the possibility of returning a value of the wrong type when writing more complex functions.

Comment: I feel none of the answers really work here. Does anyone have any updates?

Comment: This also baffles me. Is it possible that Dart simply doesn't have the syntax to explicitly declare the return type? How strange and disappointing.

Answer (score 25):

You can do something like this:

```
int Function(int x) f = (int x) {return 1 + x;};
String Function(String x, String y) concatenate = (String x, String y) {return '$x$y';};
```

<s>EDIT:
Here is a simpler way using type casting:</s>

```
int f = (int x) {return x + 1;} as int;
```

Comment: the last example is no longer valid - if it ever was

Comment: You simply created two variables `f` and `concatenate` which have functions as their values. You then stated the types of those functions to be functions. You did not create an anonymous function with a return type. That is effectively a named function.

Answer (score 6):

You can declare an anonymous, inline function just like a regular function

```
int count(int a, int b) {
  int innerThing(int c, int d) => c + d;

  return innerThing(a, b);
}
```

That might be easier.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that this was a possibility. I was hoping I could avoid it. I feel it limits the utility of anonymous functions. It's also one of the thinks I don't like about python.

Comment: This is by definition not anonymous, as the Name part is required. Its a nice workaround, but it doesnt answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Function expressions in dart can't be named.

```dart
print(int anonFunc () {}) // ERROR: Function expressions can't be named.
```

Now if we try to take out the name and leave only the type instead:

```dart
print (int () { return 20; });
```

We still get the original error because dart thinks that `int` is now the name of the closure.

So in short, it's just not possible to have return types for anonymous functions in dart.

If you plan on passing the closure as an argument to another function, then the best you can do is to add type annotations to the parameter of the higher order function receiving the closure like so:

```dart
int callClosureWithArg(int Function(int x) func, int y) {
    return func(y);
}

// Now you will get a compile error if the closure's signature
// doesn't match with the parameter's signature
callClosureWithArg((String x) {
    return x.length;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use typedef if you plan to use inline function type several times

```dart
typedef CalcCallback = int Function(int a, int b);

enum Operation {
  sum,
  diff,
}

CalcCallback calc(Operation operation) {
  CalcCallback sum = (int a, int b) => a + b;
  CalcCallback diff = (int a, int b) => a - b;

  return operation == Operation.sum ? sum : diff;
}


void main() {
  print(calc(Operation.sum)(5, 5)); // 10
  print(calc(Operation.diff)(20, 5)); // 15
}
```

Answer (score -1):

THE ANONYMOUS DART FUNCTION USES A `dynamic` data type on `retrun`